# Where I can find definitions of vector types (uchar3, float3, uint2, and alike)?

Tags: types, cuda

For now I know that such types exist, I know what fields they have, but I couldn't find a definitions for them. I.e. I found:

```
typedef __device_builtin__ struct uint2 uint2;
```

But this leaves all the questions I have intact -- what about their constructors? What about operators? And so on.

So, are the definitions (real ones) for those types published somewhere? I wouldn't like to reinvent the wheel especially not optimized (starting how to init such structure).

Comment: http://docs.nvidia.com/cuda/cuda-c-programming-guide/index.html#vector-types Have you read this?

Comment: Thank you, in pdf, yes, but does it mean it is all?

Comment: Well I don't know if there's source available. So I'd say yes. In any case why would you need to know such information? Personally I don't like this CUDA black box as even NVIDIAs' engineers don't know what's happening in there so I don't use those built-in types.

Comment: @KiaMorot, perfomance & reusability.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The definitions for most of these vector types are included in:

```
/usr/local/cuda/include/vector_types.h
```

(assuming standard cuda install path).  Most of them are structs, and don't require specific operator definitions for operating on struct members, nor do they have official c++ style constructors.

The "constructors" that you refer to e.g. `make_int2` are inline functions defined in:

```
/usr/local/cuda/include/vector_functions.h
```

Again, they are ordinary c style functions operating on structure members, not c++ style class/struct methods.

Comment: Thank you, pity though, I counted on at least comparison operators :-).