# What are vector division and multiplication as in CUDA __half2 arithmetic?

Tags: cuda, half-precision-float

`__device__​ __half2 __h2div ( const __half2 a, const __half2 b )`
**Description:**
Divides half2 input vector a by input vector b in round-to-nearest mode.

`__device__​ __half2 __hmul2 ( const __half2 a, const __half2 b )`
**Description:**
Performs half2 vector multiplication of inputs a and b, in round-to-nearest-even mode.

Can someone explain me what exact operations are happening for both of these?

Comment: It is element-wise multiplication/division. What exactly do you mean by "operations"? PTX/SASS instructions? You could use [cuda.godbolt.org](https://cuda.godbolt.org/) to see those. Or do you want an explanation of the rounding modes?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Both are elementwise operations.  A `__half2` is a [vector type](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15410954/where-i-can-find-definitions-of-vector-types-uchar3-float3-uint2-and-alike), meaning it has multiple elements (2) of a simpler type, namely `half` (i.e. 16-bit floating point quantity.)  These vector types are basically structures where the individual elements are accessed using the structure references `.x`, `.y`, `.z`, and `.w`, for vector types up to 4 elements.

If we have two items (`a`, `b`)  that are each of `__half2` type:

the division operation:

```
__half2 a,b;
__half2 result = __hdiv2(a, b);
```

will create a `result`  where the first element of `result` is equal to the first element of `a` divided by the first element of `b`, and likewise for the second element.

This means when complete, the following statements should "approximately" be correct:

```
result.x == a.x/b.x;
result.y == a.y/b.y;
```

The multiplication operation:

```
__half2 a,b;
__half2 result = __hmul2(a, b);
```

will create a `result`  where the first element of `result` is equal to the first element of `a` multiplied by the first element of `b`, and likewise for the second element.

This means when complete, the following statements should "approximately" be correct:

```
result.x == a.x*b.x;
result.y == a.y*b.y;
```

("approximately" means there may be rounding differences, depending on your exact code and possibly other factors, like compile switches)

Regarding rounding, its [no different than when these terms are applied in other (non CUDA) contexts](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/IEEE_754#Rounding_rules). Roughly speaking:

"round to nearest" is what I would consider the usual form of rounding.  When an arithmetic result is not exactly representable in the type, the nearest type representation will be chosen so that:

- if the exact result is closer to the next closest type-representable value closer to zero, the type value closer to zero will be chosen
- if the exact result is closer to the type-representable value closer to positive or negative infinity, the type value closer to positive or negative infinity will be chosen
- if the exact result is exactly at the midpoint between the two closest type-representable values, the type value closer to positive or negative infinity will be chosen.

"round to nearest even" is a modification of the above description to choose the closest type representation in the exact midpoint case that has an even numbered least significant digit.